# SPList.GetItems(SPList.DefaultView) returns only visible items

Tags: list-view, object-model

WSPList.GetItems(SPList.DefaultView) only returns the number of items set to return in throttling settings on the view. I'm aware that I can increase the item limit for the view, but the users are ultimately going to change it back, so that's basically useless.
If I don't pass a view, I get all items. Unfortunately, they're not filtered in line with the default view, they're filtered on the item ID.

I can't get it to work in CAML, because I would need to pass an empty query - I need all items, unsorted. I'm open to the idea of CAML, but I can't really come up with a way to do this successfully.

Is there an override setting or a method I am unaware of that will return all items ordered however they are in the default view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CAML query from the default view if you want, but note that you're then using both the sort order as well as any filtering from that view.

```
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = list.DefaultView.Query;
var items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: Exactly this. Users are structuring a list that I need to export as-is to order items in a spreadsheet. Filtered and sorted, but not paginated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 public static SPListItemCollection GetOrderedListItems()
 {

            SPListItemCollection items = null;

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://basesmc2008"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {

                    SPList list = web.Lists["mylinks"];

                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                    query.RowLimit = 300;
                    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Order\" /></OrderBy>";
                    items = list.GetItems(query);

                }
            }

            return items;

        }

}
```

taken from here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1064f3d8-9fd5-4bcf-9d42-cd8b9c438595/how-to-get-ordered-items-when-using-splistordered

I dont think i need to explain whats going on as its simple to understand whats going on! get list and order it lol.

Comment: It answers the all items issue, but then the list will be sorted on the field that's in CAML. It should be sorted however the users set it in the default view.

Comment: NEVER EVER create a function returning a SPList/SPListItemCollection from a SPWeb which is disposed inside the function. This is causing a memory leak as the SPWeb is brought back to live if you access the SPList/SPListItemCollection.